# Spring and web integration test of class annotated with @ConditionaOnProperty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, conditional-statements

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2.

I have a service annotated as follows

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty("${my.property.enabled:false}")
public class MyService {

}
```

and I want to test it doing an integration tests, e.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

}
```

The service is not autowired in the test. I want to avoid setting the property in a properties file inside the test folder. Can't I enable the property directly via such an annotation inside the `MyServiceTest`?

Comment: It would help to know exactly what you're trying to accomplish. It may be best simply to have an `@Configuration` class for that test specifically that declares an `@Bean MyService` unconditionally.

Comment: This approach seems interesting. How can I execute a specific configuration in MyServiceTest?

Comment: I'm not sure how the new Boot test magic works; I usually use `@ContextConfiguration`. You might try just declaring a (static) `@Configuration` nested class on your test class and see if it's picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update*

As Stephane has mentioned in the comment the property inlining for Testing purposes demonstrated below can happen in the `@SpringBootTest` directly via the `properties` parameter in which case you won't need the `@TestPropertySource`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
                properties = { "my.property.enabled = true" })
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

}
```

---

*Original Answer*

You can inline the needed property in your test config class directly using `@TestPropertySource`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "my.property.enabled = true" })
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

}
```

Also note that the annotation as you've defined it wouldn't work, maybe you meant to use `@ConditionalOnExpression` in which case it would work:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.property.enabled:false}")
public class MyService {

}
```

but the `@ConditionalOnProperty` is more expressive and in your case can be written as:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="my.property" , name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MyService {

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could update your answer to mention that `SpringBootTest` has a `properties` shortcut for this. So it would be something like `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ""my.property.enabled=true")`